# How do I create a driver.get function in Selenium that will be called from another class?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium, junit

Ok, so I am using `POM` to create a kind of framework in `Selenium/Maven`. The project has three packages

1. **Pages**(which include the different webpages I will navigate through)
2. **Test**(which will call functions and execute) and
3. **Util**(containing a Library class with functions that I want to call from classes in the Test and Pages packages)

Here is my code from the Library class:

```
package util;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class Lib {

//Question is regarding the method below
public static WebElement get(WebDriver driver, String url) {
    WebElement link = driver.get(url);
    return link;
}

public static WebElement findelement(WebDriver driver, String xpath) {
    WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
    return e;
}

public static void sleep(WebDriver driver, int sec) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(sec*1000); 
}
}
```

I want to be able to call the get method(first one) from the Lib class in the test class. Here is my code for the test class:

```
package test;

import org.junit.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

import util.Lib;

public class Test extends Lib{

static WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

@Before
public void before() {
    System.out.println("Before Class starts here");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",
            "C:\\Users\\TQ\\sel\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");

    driver = new ChromeDriver();

    Lib l = new Lib();
    l.get(driver, "https://www.google.com/");


}
}
```

I know I could easily do a `driver.get(url)` in the test class but I want to know why its not working like it is for the other functions in my lib class.

This is the error message I'm getting `"cannot convert from void to WebElement"`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm also a complete newb so any help is appreciated. Also could anyone tell me why I'm getting downvoted for this post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is void. It should look like:

```
//Question is regarding the method below
public static void get(WebDriver driver, String url) {
      driver.get(url);
}
```

That`s all. You need not to return something is this case.

Comment: Thanks for a simple answer

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the reference object of webdriver from test class to lib. Remove the `extends Lib` from test class. Create a constructor in lib class for initialising the reference object. The Library class should look something like this.

```
package util;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

public class Lib {
WebDriver driver;
public Lib(WebDriver driver){
     this.driver = driver;
}
//Question is regarding the method below
public static WebElement get(String url) {
    WebElement link = driver.get(url);
    return link;
}

public static WebElement findelement(String xpath) {
    WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath));
    return e;
}

public static void sleep(int sec) throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(sec*1000); 
}
}
```

Now , When you create the Lib object using **new** operator , you have to pass *driver instance*. The constructor will pass on the driver reference to local driver variable, which will allow Test class to use Lib class methods.

```
Lib l = new Lib(driver);
l.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

The coded way by which you passed on driver instance to method parameters will lead to null pointer exception.

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all :

```
"cannot convert from void to WebElement"
```

You have written the method **`public static WebElement get(WebDriver driver, String url) {}`**. But **get()** doesn't returns anything and is defined as :

```
get(java.lang.String url)
Load a new web page in the current browser window.

Return Type :
  void
```

Hence when you invoke **WebElement link = driver.get(url);**, the `return type` doesn't matches the function call and the error is thrown.

## Solution

The solution would be to make the return as **void**. As the `driver` opens the `URL` you can easily interact with the `Web Browser` instance through the `WebDriver` instance i.e. `driver` as follows :

```
public static void get(WebDriver driver, String url) {
    driver.get(url);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It works. However, could you explain how the `findelement(WebDriver driver, String xpath)` method needs to return a value while the `get(WebDriver driver, String url)` method doesn't?